# Can someone explain what it means when $\det A^{-1}= (\det (A))^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Does this mean that the determinant of the inverse of $A$ is equal to the inverse of the determinate of $A$, and is this always true, for $n \times n$ matrices?

Suppose the $\det(A^{-1})=5$ Does that mean then that $(\det(A))^{-1} = \frac{1}{5}$ or am I missing something? Like do I have the wrong idea of the inverse?

Comment: $\det A \det A^{-1}=\det A A^{-1}=\det I_n=1$

Comment: If $\det (A^{-1}) = 5$ then $( \det A )^{-1} = 5$.

Comment: It helps to think of the $n=1$ case. A $\,1\times 1\,$ matrix is very much like the number it contains. The determinant of it is just the number itself. Its inverse is the inverse of the number.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $A$ is invertible. Then one has
\begin{align*}
1 = \det I = \det(AA^{-1}) = \det(A)\det(A^{-1}) \Longrightarrow \det(A^{-1}) = [\det(A)]^{-1}
\end{align*}

Comment: can you explain this in words?

Comment: what is this really telling me?

Answer (score 1):

Since $\det AB =\det A \det B,$ this is just saying 
$$
1=\det I=\det (A)(A^{-1})=\det (A) \det(A^{-1})
$$

Answer (score 1):

You will never hear me say "the inverse of (some number)".  I learned years ago that it leads to exactly the confusion happening here.

The determinant of a matrix is a number and when you raise a number to the power $-1$, you obtain its reciprocal.  The equation you have written says,  "the determinant of the inverse of a matrix is the reciprocal of the determinant of the matrix."

You have written $\det (A^{-1}) = (\det A)^{-1}$.  It is perhaps more enlightening to write
$$  \det (A^{-1}) = \frac{1}{\det A}  \text{.}  $$

You ask, if $\det (A^{-1}) = 5$, what is $(\det A)^{-1}$.  Your equation says the calue of one of these is the same as the value of the other, so both of these are $5$.  Here, however, is perhaps a clearer version of what you are thinking.

Suppose $\det A = 5$.  Then $\frac{1}{\det A} = \frac{1}{5}$ and the equation says $\det(A^{-1}) = \frac{1}{5}$.